# putting frontend and backend repo into single docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Should I create multiple docker containers to host my frontend and backend source code?
With traditional approach (Nginx and Reverse proxy in Ubuntu) I don't separate them. What's the advantage of separating both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a good practice to achieve resilience, here where I work, we run 3 instances of the same container, and in the front of then, we have a load balancer, with that, if one instance is down, we have other 2 to receive the traffic.

Comment: so you're using tools like docker compose I guess?

Comment: yes, we use docker compose